# Android cache webview images?

Tags: android, listview, webview

I've `Listview` activity each row content `webview` and the `webview` content article html code with images.

So far everything is perfect, but my problem is if the `listview` scrolled the `webview` lost images and reopen them again, and the `listview` become crazy.

I want to cache`webview` images to prevent it to reopen or download the images again. How?

I am new in Android and sorry for my English.

Any advice?

This is my webview settings:

```
    holder.message.addJavascriptInterface(new test_js(context), "Android");
    holder.message.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
   // holder.message.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
    holder.message.getSettings().setTextSize(WebSettings.TextSize.NORMAL);          

    //test
    holder.message.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
    holder.message.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize( 8 * 1024 * 1024 ); // 8MB
    holder.message.getSettings().setAppCachePath(context.getApplicationContext().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath());
    holder.message.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    holder.message.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
```

but it won't cache the images it's redownloading them again when I scroll the listview!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use [Universal-Image-Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) for loading and caching images when working with `listview` or `recyclerview`. The **Universal-Image-Loader** has option `delayBeforeLoading(time)` to prevent listview's `scroll` issues when there is item with images. And to cache other content just write the body of response to file and extract it to your listview.